# WPF Layout Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, binding

I apologize for the length of this post but this one bums me out for two days straight now. Consider the image below. On Mouseclick on one of the tiles 1-4 the tiles resize and a big tile 5 appears in the middle. Another mouseclick reverses the process. 
[image: Resizing Tiles]

First I tried to bind the width/height property of row- and columndefinitions directly. This didn't work at all. The current solution uses the width and height property of labels to get the resizing done. The code is as follows...

**XAML:**

```
....
<Grid Name ="MainGrid" Background="Crimson">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="LeftGrid" Grid.Column ="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row ="0"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleLeftTop" />
        <Label Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row ="1"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleLeftSideTop" />
        <Label Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row ="2"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleLeftSideBottom"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row ="1" Background ="Green" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">    </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row ="2" Background ="Yellow" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1"></Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="RightGrid" Grid.Column ="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row ="0"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleRightTop"/>
        <Label Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row ="1"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleRightSideTop"/>
        <Label Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row ="2"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleRightSideBottom"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row ="1" Background ="Thistle " MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_2"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row ="2" Background ="Tan " MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_3"></Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="MiddleGrid" Grid.Column ="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row ="0"  Background ="Cyan " Width="200" Name="HandleMiddleTop" />
        <Grid Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row ="1" Background ="Tomato"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class RTGraphControl : UserControl
{

    private readonly RTGraphControlViewModel _viewModel;

    public RTGraphControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new RTGraphControlViewModel(this);

        DataContext = _viewModel;

        //.... Binding row heights etc...

        var leftColumnWidthbindingElement = new Binding
        {
            Source = _viewModel,
            Path = new PropertyPath("LeftColumnWidth"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
        HandleLeftTop.SetBinding(WidthProperty, leftColumnWidthbindingElement);

    // same for right and middle column           

        _viewModel.Expanded = false;

    }
}

public class RTGraphControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly RTGraphControl _rt;
    private bool _expanded;
    private double _rowHeight;
    private double _leftcolumnWidth;
    private double _middlecolumnWidth;
    private double _rightcolumnWidth;

    public RTGraphControlViewModel(RTGraphControl rt)
    {
        _rt = rt;
    }

    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return _expanded; }
        set
        {
            _expanded = value;
            double width = _rt.MainGrid.ActualWidth;
            if (_expanded)
            {
                LeftColumnWidth = width*0.2;
                RightColumnwidth = width*0.2;
                MiddleColumnWidth = width*0.6;
            }
            else
            {
                LeftColumnWidth = width * 0.5;
                RightColumnwidth = width * 0.5;
                MiddleColumnWidth = width * 0;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Expanded");
        }
    }

    public double LeftColumnWidth
    {
        get { return _leftcolumnWidth; }
        set
        {
            _leftcolumnWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LeftColumnWidth");
        }
    }

    public double MiddleColumnWidth {...}

    public double RightColumnwidth {...}

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This kind of works for the left and middle column but funnily enough it doesn't for the right column. The right column doesn't change its width at all. Another problem is that after initialization of the usercontrol actualwidth is set to 0. A workaround with .Measure and .Arrange didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: I was going to suggest a custom `Panel` but apparently that didn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your XAML like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="ForestGreen" Margin="2"
          MouseDown="OuterContainer_OnMouseDown" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="LimeGreen" Margin="2"
          MouseDown="OuterContainer_OnMouseDown" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Firebrick" Margin="2"
          MouseDown="OuterContainer_OnMouseDown" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="OrangeRed" Margin="2"
          MouseDown="OuterContainer_OnMouseDown" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="DodgerBlue"
          MouseDown="MiddleContainer_OnMouseDown" x:Name="MiddleContainer"
          Visibility="Collapsed" Width="300" Margin="2" />
</Grid>
```

Then a little code-behind to show/hide the middle box:

```
private void OuterContainer_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MiddleContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void MiddleContainer_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MiddleContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Hidden:

[image: middle box hidden]

Showing:

[image: middle box showing]

The only caveat is that the middle box has a preset size (300, but you can change that), instead of 60%. Not sure what you're intending to do with it, so that may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks so much. Quite simple solution but works as intended with some tweaks.